# ActionScript load extern gif animation into htmlText

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, gif

I'm trying to load an external GIF file using a TextField's `htmlText`. I set the `htmlText` to `<img src='98.gif' />`. 
Unfortunately the gif animation is not shown and it says :

> ProcessImageTags: can't find a resource for export name '98.gif'.

The file "98.gif" is located in the same directory with my swf file.

How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. About loading external images into an textField: it's strange, that you have a problem here. I've just tried a simple app (.fla file which is compiled to .swf in a folder where the file **test.gif** exists. And it works for me. Here is an example of my code:

> ```
> import flash.text.TextField;
>
> var field:TextField = new TextField();
> this.addChild(field);
> field.border = true;
> field.autoSize = TextFieldAutoSize.LEFT;
> field.multiline = true;
> field.wordWrap = true;
> field.width = 200;
>
> field.htmlText = "SOME TEXT <img src='test.gif'/>";
> ```

Maybe, in your case, the problem exists because of Local Security Settings. Please, check the special panel for these settings here: https://www.macromedia.com/support/documentation/en/flashplayer/help/settings_manager04.html

2. Play gif file animtations: as far as I know there is no straightforward "out-of-the-box" solution for it. Especially, for the **TextField** class (actually, I haven't heard about any solution for the **TextField** class). There are some solutions, which help to load and play gif-animations as external files, but not in the **TextField** class: http://www.bytearray.org/?p=95

As a workaround, you may try to load an external gif animation with special classes (e.g. the one I've mentioned above) and combine it visually with a regular **TextField** object (text is shown in the **TextField** and the GIF file is loaded as another **DisplayObject**).